# PHP PDO exception: could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, freebsd

Does the MySQL-server and PHP5-MySQLi version have to match in order for a connection to be possible?  I'm currently receiving the error below:  I am running BSD.
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'..."

Here is the the connection info:

```
$info = "mysql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost";
$user = "dbUser";
$pw = "somePW";
return(new PDO($info, $user, $pw));
```

Here is my MySQL information:

mysql-server-5.5.24

php5-mysqli-5.4.3

Comment: `phpinfo();` and look what PDO drivers you have. You don't have `PDO Mysql`. mysqli and PDO are 2 different DBALs, and seems like you confuse them

Comment: PDO support enabled
PDO drivers  sqlite

Comment: yep, only `sqlite` driver and no `mysql` driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO uses database specific [drivers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) to connect to database systems. It looks like you are missing the pdo_mysql driver that is required to connect to a MySQL database. There is some details on installing the driver on the [pdo_mysql manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) page, or there may be a BSD package that you can use (I am afraid I'm not familiar enough with BSD to offer specific advice).

Comment: I am not familiar with BSD either, but a quick search suggests that `php5-pdo-5.4.3` is the correct package, or close to it.

Answer (score 18):

I had this same issue on my CentOS install. I had tried to install imagick and hosed my install. When I removed all of my php files and reinstalled something wasn't working right.

I ran:

```
yum install php-pdo
yum install php-pdo_mysql
```

After doing those two lines I ran

```
service httpd restart
```

and everything came back up and running.

Comment: "No package php-mysql available." here

Comment: Without seeing your config and setup, it's a little hard to tell what going on from this statement. Check out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872600/yum-install-php-mysql-unable-to-install-centos

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to zerkms and John C for pointing me in the right direction.  Below are the commands I used to install the driver:

```
#cd /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql
#make install clean
#apachectl restart
```

Comment: Those are the right commands.  You might also want to consider installing `ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster` to help you manage installs and upgrades in the future.