# yum install php-mysql unable to install Centos

Tags: php, mysql, centos6, yum

I am having difficulty installing php-mysql, I do the following:

```
yum -y install php-mysql
```

but get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.escapemg.com
 * extras: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * updates: mirrors.xmission.com
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I did a `yum repolist disabled` and enabled `yum-config-manager --enable C6.1-base` but still keep getting the same No package php-mysql available.

Comment: What version are you trying to install?

Comment: `yum list|grep mysql` and see what's really available?

Comment: Running on Centos 6.5 and just trying to install a version that would work best for this version

Comment: This is the result of yum list| grep mysql

Comment: cpanel-mysql.x86_64                        5.1.73-1.cp1136             installed
cpanel-mysql-libs.x86_64                   5.1.73-1.cp1136             installed
cpanel-perl-514-DBD-mysql.x86_64           4.024-1.cp1136              installed
apr-util-mysql.x86_64                      1.3.9-3.el6_0.1             C6.1-base

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out, it appeared that mysql in `/etc/yum.conf` there was a line `exclude=mysql* php*` once I commented it out, I was able to `yum install mysqlnd`. Thanks to everyone who

Comment: exclude not always there, like in my newly installed AlmaLinux 8.8 (which is effectively CentOS)

Answer (score 5):

The obvious problem is that you don't have a repository with PHP installed. It's odd that base doesn't have one but you can fix this by installing the [remi repository](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en), which has PHP 5.4 through 5.6 (just enable the version you want)

I would highly suggest installing `php-mysqlnd` instead of `php-mysql`, as that is the native driver and does not require any `mysqlclientXX` libraries, which are a mess to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I installed the remi repository and enabled it, but still get a package not available when I do a `yum installphp-mysqlnd`

Comment: Try `yum install php` and see if it lists any packages