# Unable to install php-mysqli on PHP7

Tags: php, mysqli, centos

I have installed PHP 7, mysql5.7, Apache2.2, CentOS6.

And I'm installing CodeIgniter3.0.6.

When I use database connection,
error occured and said

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0
```

Of course there are no files in '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysqli.so', but I don't know how to install mysqli.so.

I tried

```
yum install php-mysql
```

but

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
           Installed: php-common-7.0.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.4-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

and it didn't work.

---

when I execute `yum install php7.0-mysql` or `yum install php70w-mysql` command,

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
No package php7.0-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I don't know what to do at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872600/yum-install-php-mysql-unable-to-install-centos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please remind that the [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) and doesn't exists anymore with PHP 7.

The **php-mysqlnd** package provides only the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) extensions.

The **php-pecl-mysql** is also available, build from a git snapshot, provided for compatibility for legacy applications, but is not supported.

From the original question:

> Installed: php-common-7.0.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)

You have php 7.0.4 installed from **remi-php70**, but the repository is not enabled. You need to enabled it, so yum will find the right package matching the installed version.

From the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions:

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

Notice: the correct command to install an "foo" extension is yum install php-foo, so "yum install php-mysql" will install the package which provides the *mysql* extension (so php-pecl-mysql), "yum install php-mysqli" will install  the packages which provides the *mysqli* extension (so php-mysqlnd).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I can install mysqli in that way and use it! It seems I need to study about "yum", "remi", "package"... or something like that.

Answer (score 13):

For PHP7, on *CentOS* / *RHEL*:

```
yum install php70w-mysql
```

if you use the *Remi* repository

```
yum install php70-php-mysqlnd
```

for *Ubuntu*:

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
But , when I execute that command.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
No package php7.0-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Yes. `$ cat /etc/centos-release` => `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`

Comment: I never used remi repository -- can you try with `yum install php70-php-mysqlnd`?

Comment: I executed that command, it seems to have been installed! `Package php70-php-mysqlnd-7.0.5-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: if it has installed, why isn't there mysql module? When I execute `php -m`, there aren't something that refers to mysql.

Comment: have you upgraded php from php5?

Comment: Please note php-mysqlnd (which is for php-common already installed) is not the same than php70-php-mysqlnd (for parallel installation of multiple version).

Comment: @Federico I'm sorry but I don't remember how to install php-7.

Comment: or for Centos and php7.1
yum install php71-php-mysqlnd