# Dockerfile: No package matches php

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I am currently trying to make a Dockerfile with the Ubi-7-minimal Baseimage (This is a must do),
to make a Joomla-Dockerimage.
Problem is, that it always says that "No package matches php"
First, my Dockerfile (I know, the CMD is missing, but thats not the point)

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi-minimal 

EXPOSE 443 80

RUN rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY* 
RUN microdnf install epel-release

RUN microdnf install httpd 

RUN microdnf install php
```

In some suggestions, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387338/unable-to-install-php-mysqli-on-php7), but no success.
Another suggestion is, to first install epel-release, but while building, it just says nothing to do when running "RUN microdnf install epel-release".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/31/working-with-red-hat-enterprise-linux-universal-base-images-ubi/ you should be installing rh-php72, not a generic php. You could try using a search command to see which php packages are available as well.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much the solution.