# How to resolve ansible playbook error installing php "No package php-mysql available"?

Tags: ansible, devops

I am trying to install `Php, Apache in RHEL` using the `Ansible Playbook`. But I am getting following error.

> *failed: [18.191.65.251] (item=[u'php', u'php-mysql', u'php-pdo', u'php-gd', u'php-mbstring']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item",
>   "changed": false, "failures": ["No package php-mysql available."],
>   "item": ["php", "php-mysql", "php-pdo", "php-gd", "php-mbstring"],
>   "msg": ["Failed to install some of the specified packages"], "rc": 1,
>   "results": []}

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBLzU.jpg)

The code that I have used to write the playbook is as follows

```
---
- hosts: all

  become: yes

  tasks:

 - name: Install httpd

    yum:

    name: httpd

    state: present

 - name: starting httpd service

    service:

    name: httpd

    enabled: yes

    state: started

- name: Installing php packages

   yum:

   name: "{{ item }}"

   state: present

 with_items:
 - php
 - php-mysql
 - php-pdo
 - php-gd
 - php-mbstring

- name: restart Apache service

   service:
   name: httpd
   state: restarted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yum install php-mysql unable to install Centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872600/yum-install-php-mysql-unable-to-install-centos)

Comment: Are you able to install it from the command line?

Comment: Side note: don't use `with_items` with yum but pass the list directly to the `name` parameter. See the [first note on the module doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#notes)

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon Linux instead of RHEL, rest code will code work.

---

- hosts: all

  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Install httpd

  yum:

  name: httpd

  state: present

  - name: starting httpd service

  service:

  name: httpd

  enabled: yes

  state: started
- name: Installing php packages

  yum:

  name: "{{ item }}"

  state: present

  with_items:

  - php
  - php-mysql
  - php-pdo
  - php-gd
  - php-mbstring
- name: restart Apache service

  service:
  name: httpd
  state: restarted