# Gii Model Generator generates Database Exception (I use SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, yii, yii2

I have a **Yii2** framework connected to an **SQL Server 2012** database.

I have already configured the **config/db.php** file as follows:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Evaluators;MultipleActiveResultSets=true',
    'username' => '_myUsername_',
    'password' => '_myPassword_',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

**I have also installed the necessary extension files in the /ext directory.**

**I am using SQL Server 2012 instead of MySql.**

When I try to Start Gii Model Generator I get the following error :

---

**Database Exception – yii\db\Exception could not find driver**

**Caused by: PDOException could not find driver**

---

Any ideas what should I change or do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO exception: could not find driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423677/php-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Did you add sqlsrv extensions in your php config ?

Comment: I did. I enabled the extensions through PHP Manager in IIS.

Comment: What is the name of the dll file for mssql pdo you are referencing in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be from your php configuration.

In that case, I solved it by doing the following: uncomment **extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll** in your php.ini. (I am on MySQL instead of SQL server 2012)

More explanations here: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/installing-php-7-and-composer-on-windows-10

Since your using SQL server 2012, I cannot confirm for sure, but you should investigate this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Good luck